# Is decimal number constraint possible in SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, constraints, decimal, sqldatatypes

### Issue

I'm using SQLite and I've got a bunch of fields representing measures in millimeters that I'd like to limit to 1 number after decimal point (e.g. `1.2` ; `12.2` ; `122.2` and so on).

I've seen such things as putting `DECIMAL(n,1)` as the type for example and I tried it but it doesn't seem to constraint the value (I suppose it's because it's not an actual SQLite type).

Do I need to migrate to MySQL for it to work?

---

### EDIT (solution found)

I used Dan04's answer : it's simple and it works really fine :

► Table is as follow :

```
CREATE TABLE demo(
a REAL CHECK(a = ROUND(a,1)),
b REAL CHECK(b = ROUND(b,1)),
c REAL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a+b)
)
```

► Insert corerct data : `INSERT INTO demo (a,b) values (41.4,22.6)`

► Insert bad data : `INSERT INTO demo (a,b) values (1.45,22.68)` outputs :

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: CHECK constraint failed: a = ROUND(a,1)
At line 1:
insert into demo (a,b) values (1.45,22.68)
```

Comment: Can't you do that at the application level?

Comment: Do you mean something like `CREATE TABLE demo(mm REAL NOT NULL CHECK(cast(mm * 10 as 'int') == mm * 10))` to prevent entry of more than 1 number after the decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `CHECK` constraint using [the `ROUND` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round).  Declare the column as:

```
mm REAL CHECK(mm = ROUND(mm, 1))
```

But note that the underlying representation is still a binary floating-point number, with the usual caveats about accuracy.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! thanks a lot ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's `DECIMAL(nn,1)` will round to 1 decimal place *for storing*.  That's not the same as a constraint.

When *displaying* data, your app should round the result to a meaningful precision.  (One decimal place is arguably over-kill for weather readings.)

In general, measurements (not money) should be stored in `FLOAT`.  This datatype (in MySQL and many other products) provides 7 "significant digits" and a reasonably high range of values.

`FLOAT` has sufficient precision when used for latitude and longitude to distinguish two vehicles, but not enough precision to distinguish two people embracing.

(Sorry, I can't speak for SQLite.  If `FLOAT` is available then I recommend you use it and round on *output*.)